# How to Extrude Edges separately along different axis

Tags: modeling, extrude

How can i Extrude a Plain like this in Blender, I just transitioned from maya to blender and I never had to deal with this problem till now, I couldn't get the extrude individually tool to work for me

[image]

[image]

Comment: I personally never saw this kind of function in Blender, i.e. extruding edges along normals and extruding edges individually (which is possible for faces: alt E), but I may be wrong

Comment: I tried extruding edges along normals it didn't work for me, extruding edges individually didn't give me accurate enough results

can I ask like, if you were to make like a plus with a plane how would you approach this

Comment: I would do it the other way around, create a plane, subdivide with a 2 cuts, delete the 4 corners. For the second picture, same thing, create a plane and inset with "i" and you have the same topology

Comment: you can also create a cube and extrude faces along normals or extrude faces individually, then delete the fop faces to only keep a plane...